# Copyright of newer weapon designs used for a novel?

Tags: copyright

What is the status on using a newer designed weapon, like the [cyclone M48 knife](https://www.unitedcutlery.com/ProductDetail.aspx?itemno=UC3427&cat=M4), in a novel? Would I run into copyright/trademark issues? The spiral design is what I am interested in more than using the name of the knife itself.
[image: M48 knife image]

Comment: Is this knife real, or fictional?

Comment: It's a real knife, but I would be using it in a fictional novel.

Comment: Gruesome kind of thing, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

### Trademarks apply to product names and not ideas.  Copyright doesn't apply to ideas or names.

You can refer to a blade's shape without fear of invoking a copyright violation. But, just because you don't use its product name or manufacturer does not mean you are clear of trademark violation.  If your usage brings a manufacturer into disrepute, and they can prove you are referring them specifically, then they can pursue legal remedy for [dilution](https://www.uspto.gov/page/about-trademark-infringement) of their value, and compel you to defend your usage as fair.

Assuming there are many manufacturers of this kind of knife or vagueness of the description, it would likely be high hurdled, but that doesn't stop anyone from suing someone else.

Comment: Thank you for your input. So basically I should be generally ok but may not be if I am too specific. I tried to upvote your post but it says I don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: And, it only matters if you get published, and the publish will tell you if it needs to be changed.

Comment: @Aurora Dizon Welcome to Writing SE! If you can't upvote, you can still "accept" it as your preferred answer.  While this answer is dead-on (I upvoted it), it's polite not to accept an answer on this site until after 24 hours, so people around the world have a chance to give another (potentially better) answer